Using the Cauchy Integral Theorem to Solve a Contour Integral
Calculate the contour integral of the given function on the unit circle:
$$f\left( t  \right) = 2\left( {t  + {1 \over t }} \right) - t \sqrt {{1 \over {{t ^2}}}{{\left( {2\left( {t  + {1 \over t }} \right) + 1} \right)}^2} - 1} $$
$$I = {1 \over {2\pi i}}\int_r {{{f(t)} \over {t - \zeta }}} dt$$
$\zeta$  is located outside the circle.
Can the singularity at $\zeta=0$ be used for the calculation? Is there a simpler method?

In the first line, you must use $, t\ \mbox{instead of}\ \zeta, $ because $\zeta$ has a particular meaning in the second line.

The function is a priori not well defined due to the branch cuts of $z\mapsto \sqrt{z}$
